# Preencher uma lista

Tags: python

Estou precisando de ajuda, estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo genético, bom meu problema é que preciso que meu loop não pare enquanto tiver espaço na lista.
Como por exemplo tenho uma população de 10 ja criada, assim que ele entra na função selecao são sorteados números aleatórios de acordo com a apitidão(fitness) e então é contruida outra população com esses números que foram "sorteados".

```
def selecao(fitness, populacao):
    populacaoIntermediaria=[]
    somatotal = sum(fitness)

    for i in range(tamPopulacao):
        r = uniform(0, somatotal)
        if (fitness[i] > r):
            populacaoIntermediaria.append(populacao[i])

    print('População Intermediaria: {}'.format(populacaoIntermediaria))

    return  populacaoIntermediaria
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Python: preencher uma lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299497/python-preencher-uma-lista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desta forma consegui resolver, assim ele preenche toda a lista com os números sorteados.

```
def selecao(fitness, populacao):
    populacaoIntermediaria=[]
    somatotal = sum(fitness)

    for j in range(tamPopulacao):
        i = 0
        parcial = 0
        r = uniform(0, somatotal)
        while (r >= parcial):
            parcial += fitness[i]
            i += 1
        populacaoIntermediaria.append(populacao[i])

    print('População Intermediaria: {}'.format(populacaoIntermediaria))

    return  populacaoIntermediaria
```